# Which is the right method to make a connection with server using volley?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley

This is may be dumb question but i could not find the solution for my problem first of all am new for android development am making connection with server using google volley to bind the recyclerview in my fragment i have written the volley connection  statement in oncreateview method whenever i open that fragment its making connection with server fetching the same record as it was before here what should i do is when response is made then only i need to fetch that data from server because of this am getting same data again and again whenever i open this fragment am really confused with this can anybody help me here let me post my code:

```
public class Task extends Fragment {
    private static final String MY_PREFERENCE_KEY = "yogan";
    private List<Model_Task_List> model_task_lists;

    //Creating Views
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Task_List_Adapter taskadapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    Task_DB task_dbobj;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        context=getActivity().getBaseContext();
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Gson gsong = new Gson();
        String jsons = sharedPreferences.getString(MY_PREFERENCE_KEY, "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Model_Task_List>>() {
        }.getType();
        model_task_lists = gsong.fromJson(jsons, type);
if(model_task_lists==null) {
    model_task_lists = new ArrayList<Model_Task_List>();
    //Showing a progress dialog
}
        taskadapter = new Task_List_Adapter(model_task_lists, getContext());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(taskadapter);



        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getActivity().getSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.login,0);
        String yogan=sharedPreferences.getString("user_id",null);

        String Url = "http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/xxx/xxx.svc/getlist/GetTask/"+yogan;
        //Creating a json array request

        JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url, new JSONObject(),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        TaskList(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("yog", error.toString());
                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        return view;
    }

    public void TaskList(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        String yogs = jsonObject.toString();
        try {
            JSONObject yog = new JSONObject(yogs);
            JSONArray yogan = new JSONArray(yog.getString("GetTaskResult"));
            for (int i = 0; i < yogan.length(); i++) {
                Model_Task_List modelobj = new Model_Task_List();

                JSONObject yogesh = yogan.getJSONObject(i);
                modelobj.setSubject(yogesh.getString("Subject"));
                modelobj.setUserName(yogesh.getString("UserName"));
                modelobj.setTaskStatus(yogesh.getString("TaskStatus"));
                model_task_lists.add(modelobj);
                taskadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


              //  task_dbobj.insert(modelobj);


            }



            //Finally initializing our adapter


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        context=getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        SharedPreferences sharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        editor = sharedpref.edit();
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        String god = gson.toJson(model_task_lists);
        editor.putString(MY_PREFERENCE_KEY, god);
        editor.commit();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

I would be very glad if someone tells the solution for my problem !!! you people are here to help beginners like us hope someone helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest to change your library, Volley is not completely upgraded to API 23 (since org.apache package is removed you will have to use legacy code), so I suggest to move to okHttp or some other library.
In case you want to stick with Volley you should create Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()); inside onCreate() method in your Application class, and then reuse same queue, not creating new one each time inside fragment.

Comment: volley is totally customizable. You can remove the legacy code too. So going with okhttp (i dont suggest) else i agree with your comment of creating a queue and reusing it :)

Comment: then which is the best way to make network call and standard way

Comment: @PunitSharma ji then using of volley is not advisable ?

Comment: @VettuKilli Check my answer ...you can use that for it !! Hopes it will help you

Comment: @PunitSharma I agree that it is possible to remove, and it is not that hard to remove it, but why do the work that is in fact somebody else job to do (Google). Honestly Volley looks better but since it is not maintained it depends on developer what does he prefer, changing somebody else code or using something that is already done and save your time.

Comment: @DoubleK But using another thing you suggests , do you think it justified not to use volley and using okhttp instead of it. In each and every comparison volley will going to perform well (like caching, imageprocessing, calling apis etc)

Comment: @PunitSharma as I said, it depends on developer and how much of work is already done, maybe changing from Volley to okHttp requires more work than removing legacy code from Volley. I had to do the same thing, but for new app I'm using okHttp because it is official, and if I continue to use Volley I won't have that "official" thing. Both Volley and okHttp work ok for me so it is more thing of preference.

Comment: Still getting the double value

Comment: @DoubleK: I have a question !! how "Okhttp" is official now :?